# How to copy textbox value to another textbox when checkbox is checked with while loop?

Tags: php, jquery

This is my code in **JQUERY :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".checkbox1").on("change",function(){

if (this.checked ) {
        $("#text2").val($("#text1").val());

    } else {

        $('#text2').attr("value", "");
        $("#text2").attr("placeholder", "text1")  ;
      }    

   });

});
```

This is my code in **PHP :**

```
 $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlquery1, $_GET['id']);
 $result = $myquery->query("SELECT * FROM `rr1` LEFT JOIN `CAL` ON 
               `rr1`.`si`=`rr2`.`sii` WHERE `rr1`.`cust`= '$id' 
                ORDER BY `si` ASC ");
 while ($myowndata = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    <td style='border:0;'><input type='text' name='si2' id='text1' value='".$myowndata['Custom']."' autocomplete='off' size='10' readonly  ></td>
    <td style='border:1px solid black'><input type='text' id='text2' name='pdcc' autocomplete='off' size='10' ></td>
    <td style='border:0px solid black;'><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxee' id='checkboxee' class='checkbox1'></td> 
     }
```

My question is :

How to copy text1's value in text2 if checkbox is checked and on using while loop? Sorry my english is bad. Although it's already working but it only works on first line. When I click other checkbox its not copying anymore.
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCwWe.jpg)

Comment: what has this question got to do with java or mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use repeated ID. Use class and find that class to get value using parent . 
Run snippet to see result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".checkbox1").on("change", function() {
    var $this = $(this).parent().parent();
    if (this.checked) {

      $this.find('.text2').val($this.find('.text1').val())

    } else {
      $this.find('.text2').val('');
      $this.find('.text2').attr("placeholder", "text1");

    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='border:0;'>
      <input type='text' name='si2' class='text1' value='".$myowndata[' Custom ']."' autocomplete='off' size='10' readonly>
    </td>
    <td style='border:1px solid black'>
      <input type='text' class='text2' name='pdcc' autocomplete='off' size='10'>
    </td>
    <td style='border:0px solid black;'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxee' id='checkboxee' class='checkbox1'>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='border:0;'>
      <input type='text' name='si2' class='text1' value='".$myowndata[' Custom ']."' autocomplete='off' size='10' readonly>
    </td>
    <td style='border:1px solid black'>
      <input type='text' class='text2' name='pdcc' autocomplete='off' size='10'>
    </td>
    <td style='border:0px solid black;'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxee' id='checkboxee2' class='checkbox1'>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you know where to learn hard codes? Like that for example I dont really know that parent function in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Check below example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#checkbox1").on("change",function(){

if (this.checked ) {
        $("#text2").val($("#text1").val());

    } else {

        $('#text2').val("");
        $("#text2").attr("placeholder", "text1")  ;
      }    

   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Text1: <input type="text" id="text1" value=""><br>
Text2: <input type="text" id="text2" value=""><br>
Check: <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" >
```

Comment: It's working but the other checkbox is not. See my image sir.

Comment: Ok for that take dynamic id and onclick() function. @MonPadi

Answer (score 0):

You have to put unique id for every row or js will always get only the first one:

```
      $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlquery1, $_GET['id']);
         $result = $myquery->query("SELECT * FROM `rr1` LEFT JOIN `CAL` ON 
                       `rr1`.`si`=`rr2`.`sii` WHERE `rr1`.`cust`= '$id' 
                        ORDER BY `si` ASC ");
        $rowID=0;
         while ($myowndata = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            <td style='border:0;'><input type='text' name='si2' id='text1-'.$rowID value='".$myowndata['Custom']."' autocomplete='off' size='10' readonly  ></td>
            <td style='border:1px solid black'><input type='text' id='text2-'.$rowID name='pdcc' autocomplete='off' size='10' ></td>
            <td style='border:0px solid black;'><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxee' id='checkboxee' class='checkbox1' rID=$rowID ></td> 
$rowID++;
             }
```

And js should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".checkbox1").on("change",function(){
var rowID = $(this).attr("rID");
if (this.checked ) {
        $("#text2-"+rowID).val($("#text1-"+rowID).val());

    } else {

        $('#text2-'+rowID).attr("value", "");
        $("#text2-"+rowID).attr("placeholder", "text1")  ;
      }    

   });

})
```

Comment: check my image sir. Just added now. Thank you :)